# INSERT conflict on _id when _id is autogenerated

Tags: c#, sql-server

i'm getting this error

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK__Subjects__fk_sub__6383C8BA". 
The conflict occurred in database "The Library", table "dbo.Subjects", column '_id'.
```

The `_id` is identity and unique and primary. and should be generated automatic when content is entered into the database.

My sql for creating the table.

```
create table Subjects
(
    _id integer identity not null,
    unique(_id),
    primary key(_id),
    subject varchar(50) not null,
    [content] varchar(MAX) not null,
    fk_subfolderTo integer not null,
    foreign key(fk_subfolderTo) references Subjects(_id),
    signed varchar(150) not null,
    fk_writer integer not null,
    foreign key(fk_writer) references Users(_id)
)
```

and the C# code for inserting into the table.

```
public static void Create (SqlConnection con, int userId, string subject, string content, string signed, int subfolderTo)
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("Insert into Subjects (subject, [content], fk_subfolderTo, signed, fk_writer) values ('" + subject + "', '" + content + "', " + subfolderTo + ", '" + signed + "', " + userId + ")", con))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

im using MSSQL.

Comment: why you use as reference same table [ foreign key(fk_subfolderTo) references Subjects(_id)]??

Comment: Cause you can have a sub-subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is being generated. The problem is whatever you're passing as a subfolder ID is not in the existing data set.

I'd also advise setting fk_subfolderto as nullable, or you'll be forced to end up with subjects being sub-subjects of themselves.

Also, you should use [parameterised queries](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx), rather than building your SQL by string concatenation before you experience a SQL Injection nightmare.